# How to add date AND time to google sheet cells in an online form filled by an html form

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheets which is populated automatically by an HTML form from a website. I need the exact date and time of users who have entered their info. So, when they fill their info and pres submit button, I get not only their info, but also the exact time that they've submitted the form. I also don't want different locations send different time, is it possible to set a GMT in google sheet, so that all date and time are evaluated according same GMT.

Here is the code for editing a cell, However, it is only works when updating a cell not adding new cell. How can I modify it to update once a new row (or cell) is added.:

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT+8:30";
  var timestamp_format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "date";
  var timeStampColName = "Date Sent";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Attendance'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Comment: Include your code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't use a simple or installable triggers to update a spreadsheet when changes are made by code. Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

The alternative is to enhance the code that makes the changes to the spreadshee to also add the required values.